# Find the range for the function

Tags: functions

Let $f: (0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$ be a function defined as $f(x) = x^{1/x}$ then the range of f is

1. $(0,\infty)$
2. $(0,1]$
3. $(0, e^{1/e}]$
4. $[e^{1/e},\infty)$

Please suggest how to solve.

Comment: You should show how you attempted to solve the problem. That way others will respond to your post.

Comment: have you tried graphing it?

Comment: Do you know how to use l'hopitals rule?

Comment: No, I didn't. I should try.

Comment: @Arbuja Yes. But for this shall I take log on both sides to solve?

Comment: Hint: Get the derivative $f'(x)$ and equate to zero. Then, eventually, you will see that the graph attains its maximum at $x=e^{1/e}$

Comment: As @ΘΣΦGenSan suggested you take the derivative and solve for zero but also substitute the end points of the interval. If both endpoints have an indeterminate output use l'hospitals.

Comment: I tried with your inputs like x^(1/x) = e^(ln x /x). Taking y = ln x/x. Applied l'Hopital. When x->0, y -> inf and x -> inf, y->0. On substitution I got (0,1]. Is this approach correct?

Answer (score 1):

We have $f(x)=x^{\frac{1}{x}}$. Then we get
$$\begin{align}
\ln f(x)=\ln x^{\frac{1}{x}}&\implies \ln f(x)=\frac{\ln x}{x}\\
&\implies \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}=\frac{x(1/x)-\ln x}{x^2}\\
&\implies f'(x)=f(x)\cdot \frac{1-\ln x}{x^2}
\end{align}.$$

Setting $f'(x)=0$ yields $x=e$ as a critical value. You can use either First Derivative Test or Second Derivative Test to establish that $(e,e^{1/e})$ is the relative maximum of the graph. Because the domain of $f$ is the interval $(0,+\infty)$, it follows that the point $(e,e^{1/e})$ is indeed the absolute maximum of the graph. Hence, the range is given by the interval $(0,e^{1/e}]$.